# Apache Airflow transferring multiple files

Tags: python, automation, airflow

I am pretty new to Airflow so this is probably a trivial questions. I have a directory on the server where Airflow runs that contains multiple files and I want to transfer them to a remote server. I am able to transfer a single file just fine but how would do I incorporate logic to transfer all the files in the directory with a single task or creating a dynamic task where I pass in the file name in a for loop.

Here is my minimalistic dag that transfers a single file.

```py
import os
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.providers.sftp.operators.sftp import SFTPOperator, SFTPOperation
from airflow.configuration import conf


fileTest = 'test.zip'

conf = {
    "start_date": datetime(2022, 6, 1),
    "catchup": False,
    "schedule_interval": "@daily",
    "dag_id": "KPO_test"
}


# instantiate the DAG
with DAG(**conf) as dag:
 
    task_push_tr_cr_files = SFTPOperator(
        task_id=f'put_{fileTest}',
        ssh_conn_id=SFTP_CONNECTION_ID,
        local_filepath=f"{SFTP_SOURCE_TR_CURL_PATH}{fileTest}",
        remote_filepath=f"{SFTP_DESTINATION_TR_CURL_PATH}{fileTest}",
        operation=SFTPOperation.PUT,
        create_intermediate_dirs=True,
        dag=dag,
)
task_push_tr_cr_files
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a TaskGroup was the solution I was looking for.

```py
...

from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup

...

t0 = DummyOperator(task_id='start')

with TaskGroup(group_id='tr_curl_grp') as tg1:
    for task_name in tr_curl_log_files:
        fileName = task_name
        task_name = f"file: {task_name}"
        task_name = SFTPOperator(
            task_id=task_name,
            ssh_conn_id=SFTP_CONNECTION_ID,
            local_filepath=SFTP_SOURCE_PING_PATH + fileName,
            remote_filepath=SFTP_DESTINATION_PING_PATH + fileName,
            operation=SFTPOperation.PUT,
            create_intermediate_dirs=True,
            dag=dag,
        )

...

t0 >> tg1
```